# Is throwing a function compliant with ES5/ES6 standard?

Tags: javascript, function, throw, iife

Is following code compliant with the standards (strict/sloppy)? It acts similar to an IIFE, but maybe readability has improved IMHO:

```
try {
    throw function (){}
} catch(foo) {
    foo();
}
```

I don't know about performances.

Comment: Well, it runs, but the purpose of the try/catch is quite opaque, why not just call the function? Readability looks much diminished IMO

Comment: try/catch is an useful polyfill for let variables for example, if you (not you CertainPerformance, I'm talking in general) know js it shouldn't be so opaque. I know that it runs, IDK if it is standard compliant.

Comment: That's what Babel is for - no need to mangle your code manually, just write in the latest and greatest version of the language and run it through the transpiler during your build process

Comment: I know Babel...but I want to know if this is compliant code and if I can use it.

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta - From both a readability/maintenance standpoint and a performance standpoint, I would use an IIFE, not this try/catch, if you need a new scope in an ES5 environment. Throwing is for exceptions, not mainline code, and is likely optimized (or rather, not) accordingly. :-) But you'd have to test it on your target environments to know the degree of impact.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okey thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can throw any value, including a function reference. What you throw doesn't have to be an Error (though that's best practice).

You can see in the specification that [`throw`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-throw-statement) accepts any [*Expression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-Expression), which can result in any value, and [`catch`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-catchclauseevaluation) faithfully provides the value thrown.

Comment: Okey thanks! If mine is a function expression I think there are no other problems. Because I know that function declarations inside {} blocks are not standard compliant. Do you know something about performances?

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta - I [just commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023649/is-throwing-a-function-compliant-with-es5-es6-standard/52023706#comment90997698_52023649) on the question about that.